# Check session state OnStart

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

When developing a Windows Service in VB.NET you have the ability to track changes in the current session (like Logon, Logoff or ConsoleConnect). The code below gives you an example of this. This procedure only runs when the current session changes. It does not run when the service is started.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnSessionChange(changeDescription As System.ServiceProcess.SessionChangeDescription)
    MyBase.OnSessionChange(changeDescription)

    If changeDescription.Reason = ServiceProcess.SessionChangeReason.ConsoleConnect Then
        'Do stuff
    End If
End Sub
```

My question is: How can i check the current session state when the service starts? Is the user logged in? Is he connected through a console session? The same things you can track through the `OnSessionChange` procedure.

Comment: If the service is set to start automatically then it will (usually) start before anyone has logged onto the machine or a session started. What are you trying to achieve? There may be a better way of going about it.

Comment: You are absolutely right, Matt. But a foolproof service can be restarted in the middle of a user session. My final goal is to have user interaction (GUI) with my service. That would only be possible when i know that a user is logged in.

Comment: Adding a GUI to your service is not good design. I would recommend looking at WCF. Using that your user can attempt to connect to your service. This attempt will fail if the service is not running.

Comment: I will take a look at WCF. But it sounds like it requires a second application polling the service. My bad design doesn't require that.

Comment: Having a GUI in your service requires that you have 'Interact with the desktop' enabled on the service. A user who logs on to the machine may not the required privileges to enable this. Even if they do, when they use the GUI they have to switch to a virtual desktop in order to see it. This is because services are not designed to have a GUI. Yes you would need a second application to communicate with the service if you use WPF but you don't have to poll it.

Comment: Have a look at these answers to see why you can't/shouldn't have a GUI: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/180833/why-cant-windows-services-have-a-gui